# Trouble retrieving information from 4d array after np.roll on one axis

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to write some code that will save a set amount of buffer frames from a video to an array and later output them once a certain criteria is met. For whatever reason my frames are being 'scrambled' when I put them through the array and coming out looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilYc7.jpg). This is all a little over my head so I don't really know what to look for but if anyone knows why my frames are being scrambled I would appreciate some input.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

interval = 1
inputclip = 'Clip.mp4'
outputclip = 'outtest.avi'
buffer = 30
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputclip)
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, nchannels = frame.shape
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter( outputclip,fourcc, 60, (width,height))

#4d array which stores the buffer frames
frameArray = np.empty((buffer, 1080,1920,3))

while(True):

    #roll frameArray to the 'right' one place then save a new frame to the first index
    frameArray = np.roll(frameArray, 1, axis=0)
    frameArray[1] = frame

    # new frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # show video
    cv2.imshow('Type "q" to close.',frame)

    # output video to file
    out.write( frame )

    # check for keystroke
    key = cv2.waitKey(interval) & 0xFF

    # exit if so-commanded
    if key == ord('q'):
        print('received key q' )
        break

#write buffer frames in the proper order        
for i in range(0,buffer):
    out.write(frameArray[buffer-1-i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default type of NumPy array is `float`, you should set the type of `frameArray` to `np.uint8`.

The following line:

```
frameArray = np.empty((buffer, 1080,1920,3))
```

Allocates an empty array of type `float`.

The following line:

```
frameArray[1] = frame
```

Places an array of type `np.uint8` in index 1 of `frameArray`.
NumPy converts the type to `float` without a warning...
It's not a "normal" conversion like type casting, but "viewing" the frame as `float` instead.

`np.roll(frameArray, 1, axis=0)`, rolls `frameArray` as array of type `float`.
The result is "confusing".

---

**Solution:**

Allocate `frameArray` as type `np.uint8`:

```
frameArray = np.empty((buffer, height, width, nchannels), np.uint8)
```

Apparently the type of an empty NumPy array is important...

---

Other issues:

- Don't forget to release `VideoWriter` at the end.
  Releasing `VideoCapture` is also recommended:

  ```
   cap.release()
   out.release()
  ```
- I think `frame` should be placed at `frameArray[0]`, and not at `frameArray[1]`:

  ```
   frameArray[0] = frame
  ```
- You have missed the first frame.
  You may add the following line above the loop:

  ```
   frameArray[0] = frame
  ```
- It looks like you need to start writing to the output video file, only when `frameArray` buffer is full.

---

Here is the complete code:
(The code includes few modification, I have made for testing).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

interval = 1
inputclip = 'Clip.mp4'
outputclip = 'outtest.avi'
buffer = 10

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(inputclip)
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, nchannels = frame.shape
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(outputclip, fourcc, 60, (width, height))

#4d array which stores the buffer frames
frameArray = np.empty((buffer, height, width, nchannels), np.uint8)

frameArray[0] = frame  # Keep the first frame.

frame_counter = 0  # Count frames

while(True):
    # Roll frameArray to the 'right' one place then save a new frame to the first index
    frameArray = np.roll(frameArray, 1, axis=0)
    frameArray[0] = frame

    # New frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Show video
    cv2.imshow('Type "q" to close.', frame)

    # Output video to file, only when the buffer is full.
    if frame_counter >= buffer:
        out.write(frameArray[-1])  # Write the last frame in frameArray.

    # Check for keystroke
    key = cv2.waitKey(interval) & 0xFF

    # Exit if so-commanded
    if key == ord('q'):
        print('received key q')
        break

    frame_counter += 1


# Write buffer frames in the proper order
for i in range(0, buffer):
    out.write(frameArray[buffer-1-i])

# Must execute release!
cap.release()
out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Close the window at the end.
```